# Palm detection not working in xfce on Ubuntu Studio 15.10

Tags: 15.10, touchpad, xfce, synaptics

I tried to configure palm detection on xfce, like it worked fine in Ubuntu 15.04:

```
TOUCHPAD_STRING="touchpad"
TP=$(xinput --list --short | grep -i $TOUCHPAD_STRING | cut -f 1 | cut -d" " -f 5- | sed 's/\s\+$//g')
xinput --set-prop "$TP" "Synaptics Palm Detection" 1
xinput --set-prop "$TP" "Synaptics Palm Dimensions" 5, 5
```

everything seems correct: `echo $TP`:

```
SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad
```

and

```
xinput --list-props "$TP"|grep Palm
```

shows the correct setting:

```
Synaptics Palm Detection (320): 1
Synaptics Palm Dimensions (321):    5, 5
```

But these settings seem to have no effect on Ubuntu Studio 15.10

How can I make this work?

Comment: It is not related to xfce. It depends on a touchpad model. Please ass output of `xinput` to your question.

Comment: @Pilot6 sure this is related to xfce, in Unity on the same mashine it works

Comment: Run `syndaemon -i 1 -K -d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `syndaemon -i 1 -K -d` to startup applications.

Probably Ubuntu Studio has not it on default.

You can also play with parameters. I use

```
syndaemon -i 2 -tKRd
```

You can get details by running `man sysdaemon`

**You will need to disable the palm detection option in system settings. Otherwise the cursor may freeze if two instances of syndaemon is running.**

Comment: Is this permanent? Or do you have to add it to your start applications?

Comment: It is not permanent. You can add it to startup applications.